# Getting a list of all VMs from all Projects in GCP

Tags: powershell, shell, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am new to GCP, and trying to get a list of all the VMs excluding GKEs from all the projects in a GCP organization. I wanted to check if anyone was able to do it using a script or a command, perhaps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can get the list of VMs for a single project but not from all the projects recursively. There are quite a few projects to get the list of VMs manually.

Comment: Have a look to asset inventory. https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview

Comment: Thank you for the response @guillaumeblaquiere. I actually was able to get a list of all the instances using the asset inventory. Another issue now is that I want to add the OS dist list to all the VM instance as well. Is there any way we can join the OS table, like you could do in Azure ?

Comment: Please do not ask a new question in the comments. Instead, create a new question with details. Also, post an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies. I was able to run the query to filter out only VM instances and exclude GKE instances from all projects using the following query

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources \
--scope='organizations/<Organization ID>' \
--query='NOT labels:goog-gke-node' \
--asset-types='compute.googleapis.com/Instance' \
--order-by='createTime'
```